# Unable to boot from HDD

Tags: boot, usb-drive, hdd

I am new at elementary OS and alternative OS in general. I've just installed elementary in my laptop (Acer Aspire 512, which was extremely slow even it is pretty new) and I am not able to boot from the HDD. If I unplug my USB I get a message telling me that there is no USB unit detected. Only when I plug it back I can boot. Is this normal? Is it not possible to boot directly from the HDD?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you verified that the BIOS settings are configured such that the computer is set to boot from the hard drive, and not an external device?

Comment: I'm having a similar (same?) problem. I'm able to boot Windows 10, or from the memory stick ('test run'), but can't boot from the Hard drive. If I go into BIOS, I see 4 options for boot priority: Windows, USB, LAN, or CD.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the grub bootloader didn't get installed correctly when you setup elementary, did you install it using the default erase and install, install besides "insert os" or the manual partitioning?

It could also be a bad download when you got the iso file, try redownloading the ISO and putting it on the USB and reinstall Elementary OS

If you installed it in UEFI mode, go into bios and make sure UEFI is enabled